# Android: Why it is not possible to upload to facebook album "Profile Pictures"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

```
GraphRequest imagesAlbumPost = new GraphRequest(token, "/1325165102/photos",
                bundle, HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        uploadedPhotoId = "";
                        Log.d("Image Post", "Res =" + response.toString());
                    }
                });
```

`1325165102` is the id of album `Profile Pictures` (dummy id)

It gives the following exception:

> {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 220, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#220) Album or albums not visible}}

Is it normal? Is there any way to upload picture to `Profile Pictures`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not upload to the user’s profile pictures album any more.

You can only upload to an album created for your app (Facebook will do that automatically, if you post to /me/photos) or you can upload to specific album other than "Profile Pictures" album, and then the user can select to use that image as their new profile image themselves via the Facebook UI.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will accept this answer, hoping it is correct. I was trying to get feedback from  someone who tried it and knows it.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is possible to upload to facebook album “Profile Pictures” but for that u have to create the test users and only to those test users, you can upload pictures

Comment: What about actual users who are going to use this app ?

Comment: after you get, the required permission from facebook then the rest of users will be also be able to upload pictures and till that period you have to work with test users.

Comment: yes, u have to ask facebook for required permissions...if you are satisfied by my answer then accept it.

Comment: @TheGreat004, by "request permission", do you mean "Submission for Approval"?